# how to solve unhandled mamaged exception in xamarino.ios?

Tags: c#, ios, exception, button, xamarin.ios

I am new to this. Please do not give me minus reputation & block. My problem is i have a button in xamarin.ios. I used that button to read list of data from a table view & value is upload to php server. But when i click on button, i got unhandled managed exception argument out of range. How can i solve this. please help  me out genius.

```
buton.TouchUpInside +=(s,e)=>{
String v=Vendor[0];
string url="my.something.com/ios_files.php?id=24&vendor="+v;
string myParam="";
using (WebClient client=new WebClient())
{
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType]="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
String Result=client.UploadString(url,myParam);
Console.writeLine(Result);
}
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You handle the exception:

```
buton.TouchUpInside +=(s,e)=> {
    try {
        String v=Vendor[0];
        string url="my.something.com/ios_files.php?id=24&vendor="+v;
        string myParam="";
        using (WebClient client=new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType]="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            String Result=client.UploadString(url,myParam);
            Console.writeLine(Result);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // do something useful, probably show an error message to the user
        Console.WriteLine (ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i will try and let you know what was happen with this.. thanks

Comment: Argument is out of range exception caused.. what can i do now?

Comment: Now it isn't unhandled anymore. If you want to know exactly how to fix the exception itself, please provide a lot more information (the complete stack trace for instance).

Comment: hi,,,i fixed. thanks for ur help. really its helpful... thank u Rolf Bjame Kvinge